# Typing React Context with Flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

We're using Flow in our project and I'm chasing my tail on this one. Am using React Context to store a user's favourite assets, this will be used in multiple places. I can't get Flow happy with React Context whose `value` is an object as follows:

```
// this is the problem line!! currently having to $FlowIgnore it
export const FavoriteAssetsContext = React.createContext(undefined);

// this is all fine
export function FavoriteAssetsProvider({
  children,
}: FavoriteAssetsProviderProps): React.Node {
  const [favoriteAssets, setFavoriteAssets] = useState([]);
  const [favoriteAssetIds, setFavoriteAssetIds] = useState([]);

  const _isFavorite = (asset: Asset): boolean => { // private func };

  const addFavorite = useCallback((asset: Asset): void => {
    //  exported function - performs setState, no return value
  });

  const removeFavorite = useCallback((asset: Asset): void => {
    //  exported function - performs setState, no return value
  });

  return (
    <FavoriteAssetsContext.Provider
      value={{ favoriteAssets, favoriteAssetIds, addFavorite, removeFavorite }}
    >
      {children}
    </FavoriteAssetsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

So the consumers of the context can access four properties on the `value` object. Flow is complaining about the lack of typing of the `FavoriteAssetsContext` which we export.

Per the Flow [docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/context/) I've tried this:

```
type FavoriteAssetsContextType = {
    favoriteAssets: Array<Asset>,
    favoriteAssetIds: Array<string>,
    addFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
    removeFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
};

export const FavoriteAssetsContext = React.createContext<FavoriteAssetsContextType>({});
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Cannot determine the type of this call expression. Please provide an annotation, e.g., by adding a type cast around this expression. [signature-verification-failure]

I have tried several permutations and combinations of [type casting](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) per Flow docs, which all look horribly wrong. It's complaining about the right hand side so I tried the following syntax:

```
// without generic - shouldn't be needed right?
export const FavoriteAssetsContext = (React.createContext({}) : FavoriteAssetsContextType);
// and with generic - ???
export const FavoriteAssetsContext = (React.createContext<FavoriteAssetsContextType>({}) : FavoriteAssetsContextType);
```

but both times I get

> Cannot cast React.createContext<...>(...) to FavoriteAssetsContextType because property removeFavorite is missing in React.Context [1] but exists in FavoriteAssetsContextType [2]. [prop-missing]

The docs have simple examples whereby the `value` is a simple string and an extensive search hasn't come up with anything examples where `value` is an object. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type FavoriteAssetsContextType = {
    favoriteAssets: Array<Asset>,
    favoriteAssetIds: Array<string>,
    addFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
    removeFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
};

export const FavoriteAssetsContext = React.createContext<FavoriteAssetsContextType>({});
```

This one solution is in the right direction however currently content is initialised with the empty object (`{}`), but in the type that is provided in the `FavoriteAssetsContextType` there are expected values for all the keys in it.

So the solution can be to update `FavoriteAssetsContextType` making all keys optional:

```
type FavoriteAssetsContextType = {
    favoriteAssets?: Array<Asset>,
    favoriteAssetIds?: Array<string>,
    addFavorite?: (asset: Asset) => void,
    removeFavorite?: (asset: Asset) => void,
};
```

Or to make an empty object acceptable value:

```
type FavoriteAssetsContextType = {
    favoriteAssets: Array<Asset>,
    favoriteAssetIds: Array<string>,
    addFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
    removeFavorite: (asset: Asset) => void,
} | {};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'm working on a different project but should be able to try later on in the week - will report back!